# How can i make my project to run in mulitiple screens?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I have developed a project and it contains many images and i have added the same images in different resolutions in three folders hdpi, mdpi, and ldpi.
But the layout i have designed is for bigger size screens and when i run the applicationi in smaller size screens what happens is the postion of components changes because of mobile screen resolution change. I got a solution for this to have a different layouts as layout, layout-small, layout-medium and layout-xlarge. I tried this and works fine but do i have any other method without making same layout in different folders.please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **dp** instead of **px** in the layout creation. and use different images for ldpi, hdpi and mdpi..and add these lines in the manifest file.

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/androids">
    <Button android:layout_width="80dp" 
   
    android:text="Exit" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_x="120dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="392dp"
     android:shadowColor="#00FFFF"
      android:color="#FFFFFF" android:onClick="exit"></Button>
</AbsoluteLayout>

Comment: in xml ok, look at images use different images for  ldpi, hdpi and mdpi. 240*320, 320*480, 480*800. are you mentioned in manifest for supporting screens..